# Autolayout: keep view's centerX same with another View but not overstep its superView

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

There are two subviews in yellow view: red view and green view. Both of them have fixed width and height. 
greenView has two more constraint: leading and bottom to the yellow View. 
redView has two more constraint: vertical space between bottom to the greenView's top and same centerX with greenView. (Figure 1)[image] (Figure 1)

What I need to do is, always keep redView inside of the yellow View, even if green view's leading constraint to the yellow view is Zero.(Figure 2) What should I do with AutoLayout? Any idea? Thanks. 
[image](Figure 2)

Comment: If the two views can have different center positions why are you giving center constraint of red view with respect to green view? Try giving center constraint with respect to yellow view, i.e. super view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Sample]

This example makes 3 constraints to the orange view:

```
1. Leading space >= 0 (priority 1000)
2. Trailing Space >= 0 (priority 1000)
3. CenterX to the green box (priority 999)
```

Result: (I forgot to remove the margin)
[image: Sample2]

Comment: Very Appreciate for your help! Your answer works well.